# Offlline payment option in addition to Stripe payment

Tags: cognito-forms

We need to offer users two payment options:

- immediate online card payment, and
- offline payment based on the invoice.

I'm not sure how this can be set up.

I've got the payment element in the form (not connected to Stripe yet, but will do later) plus there is a choice field with these two payment options.

How do I make it work to only move on to online payment if that option was selected?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/).

We only offer the ability to have payment collected at the time the form is submitted. The payment is sent though the payment gateway Stripe or PayPal. We do not offer the ability to collect payment information for an offline or pay later option. The ability to pay for only part of the total is a feature on our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/iClvWf6Q).